# Permutations with very large list

Tags: python, performance, out-of-memory, permutation

I'm trying to run a very large permutation using Python. The goal is to pair items in groups of four or less, separated by 1) periods, 2) dashes, and 3) without any separation. The order is important.

```
# input
food = ['', 'apple', 'banana', 'bread', 'tomato', 'yogurt', ...] `

# ideal output would be a list that contains strings like the following:
apple-banana-bread (no dashes before or after!)
apple.banana.bread (using periods)
applebananabread (no spaces)
apple-banana (by combining with the first item in the list, I also get shorter groups but need to delete empty items before joining)
... for all the possible groups of 4, order is important

# Requirements:
# Avoiding a symbol at the beginning or end of a resulting string
# Also creating groups of length 1, 2, and 3
```

I've used `itertools.permutations` to create an itertools.chain (`perms`). But then, this fails with a `MemoryError` when removing empty elements after converting to a list. Even when using a machine with a large amount of RAM.

```
food = ['', 'apple', 'banana', 'bread', 'tomato', 'yogurt', ...] `
perms_ = itertools.permutations(food, 4)
perms = [list(filter(None, tup)) for tup in perms]     # remove empty nested elements, to prevent two symbols in a row or a symbol before/after
perms = filter(None, perms)                            # remove empty lists, to prevent two symbols in a row or a symbol before/after

names_t = (
['.'.join(group) for group in perms_t] +     # join using dashes
['-'.join(group) for group in perms_t] +     # join using periods
[''.join(group) for group in perms_t]        # join without spaces
)

names_t = list(set(names_t))                 # remove all duplicates
```

How can I make this code more memory efficient so that it doesn't crash for a large list? If I need to, I can run the code separately for each item separator (commas, periods, directly joined).

Comment: You've hit the crux of the problem rather abruptly: you *cannot* turn your myriad permutations into a list.  Rather, you will need to set up a chain of generators to process the items in order.  If you need the final sequence as a list for some reason, do that *only* at the end of the final generator.

Comment: Let's do a little side math...  what is the size of the original list so we can think about the size of the set of permutations, which is the right way to go here.

Comment: @JeffH the original list has 287 objects, which comes out to ~6.6 billion if my math is right

Comment: @octothorpe_not_hashtag agree with your math.  That's probably not practical as stated in other comment.  So, let's back up and figure out what your original intent with said list is.  There is almost certainly another way to move forward rather than a 6B member list.

Comment: @JeffH I'm looking to save the output as part of a genomics research project. I've been able to use a server with 768 GB of RAM so I'm surprised that even that would fail (although it made it most of the way through..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I'm not too sure what you would do with a saved list of 6B things, but I think you have 2 strategies if you want to go forward.

First, you could reduce the size of the things in the list by substituting something like a `numpy` unit8 for each item, which would reduce the size of the resulting list by a LOT, but you would not have the format you want.

```
In [15]: import sys                                                             

In [16]: import numpy as np                                                     

In [17]: list_of_strings = ['dog food'] * 1000000                               

In [18]: list_of_uint8s = np.ones(1000000, dtype=np.uint8)                      

In [19]: sys.getsizeof(list_of_strings)                                         
Out[19]: 8000056

In [20]: sys.getsizeof(list_of_uint8s)                                          
Out[20]: 1000096
```

Second, if you just want to "save" the items to some kind of massive file, you do NOT need to realize the list in memory.  Just use `itertools.permutations` and write the objects to the file on-the-fly.  No need to create the list in memory if you just want to push it to a file...

```
In [48]: from itertools import permutations                                     

In [49]: stuff = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']                                        

In [50]: perms = permutations(stuff, 2)                                         

In [51]: with open('output.csv', 'w') as tgt: 
    ...:     for p in perms: 
    ...:         line = '-'.join(p) 
    ...:         tgt.write(line) 
    ...:         tgt.write('\n') 
    ...:                                                                        

In [52]: %more output.csv                                                       
dog-cat
dog-mouse
cat-dog
cat-mouse
mouse-dog
mouse-cat
```